# Best way to compare 2 binarys in windows

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, cloudflare, bypass

So i have 2 chromedrivers the first one is the original from the official repository https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.75/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip
and the other is this one https://github.com/AntidetectBrowser/ChromeDriverBypassCloudflareForWindow this one is the same version but this one is edited from source code and recompiled. and i wanted to know what changes are in this file but the owner didnt say anything is there any way to compare these 2 files to see what did he changed?

Comment: You realistically cannot compare compiled code in this way.  Even if you do compare the binary files to one another, it would be compiled code, as in machine assembly. So unless you know machine language and are  able to recognized individual instructions you are up a creek without any way to identify the paddle.

Comment: As @Ramhound states, it would likely be pointless, but there are **many** tools for comparing files in Windows OS, e.g., fc (https://www.windowscentral.com/how-compare-two-files-command-prompt-windows-10) and third-party WinMerge (https://winmerge.org/?lang=en)

Comment: You could compare changes using any simple compare tool to the source (you provided links to both) assuming they are represented in the output binary.  If you don't know how to  read code diffs (as in the source code itself), you will need more skills to deduce the differences.